# Access-VBA: Determining slope using excel.application.slope

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a database in access that contains audits for well servicing rigs. There are 17 different criteria on which the a rig is graded. Multiple companies provide rigs and I designed a query that totals the number of satisfactory/unsatisfactory scores for each company and criteria to arrive at a percentage score for each criterion. I am exporting the data to excel and automatically creating graphs for each criterion for each company, but I would also like to just have the slope handy for each criterion within access so next to their overall score I can indicate whether or not they are improving.

Using this site as a basis (http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/913231-creating-slope-formula-access), I have adapted the code for my purposes.

```
Public Sub slopeTest()
' Excel: slope(known_y's, known_x's)
'   known_y's - an array or cell range of numeric dependent data points
'   known_x's - the set of independent data points
'
'   Below creates two arrays to input into excel.slope function

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb

Dim arrX() As Double
Dim arrY() As Double
'Make sure to 1st set a Reference to the Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'for each query
    'create sql to pull that query data into a recordset
        'loop recordset
            'setup x,y array

For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
   ‘the related queries are numbered ‘xx – criteria’
    If IsNumeric(Left(qdf.Name, 2)) Then
    ‘the table graphCompanySource contains the company,associated query name,date of inspection,
 satisfactory tally,unsatisfactory tally, totalcount tally, percent satisfactory – some of the data
 was inherited so the dates are still in text format (thus the CDate())
        strQuerySQL = "SELECT * FROM [graphCompanySource] WHERE [Query] = '" & qdf.Name & "' ORDER BY CDate([InspDate]) Asc;"
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuerySQL)
        ‘loop through the recordset expanding the array with each increment
        Do Until rs.EOF
            ctr = ctr + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrX(ctr)
            ReDim Preserve arrY(ctr)
            Debug.Print qdf.Name, ctr, rs!InspDate, rs!PercSat, UBound(arrX)
            ‘arrX will just contain a sequential count
            arrX(ctr) = ctr
‘arrY should have the percentSatisfactory for each date
            arrY(ctr) = rs!PercSat

            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        ‘here I was just checking to make sure that the arrays were populated correctly
        For x = 1 To UBound(arrX)
            Debug.Print arrX(x), arrY(x)
        Next x
       ‘print the slope
        MsgBox qdf.Name & ": " & Round(objExcel.Application.slope(arrY, arrX), 6)
    End If

   ctr = 0
Next qdf

Set db = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

So for the first measure the above code produces a slope of .046703. I also tried using 'objExcel.WorksheetFunction.Slope(arrY,arrX) and arrived at the same answer. The debug showing the contents of the array produces:

```
1             0.5
2             1
3             1
4             1
5             1
6             1
7             1
8             1
9             1
10            1
11            1
12            1
```

The graph that is already constructed shows a slope of .0192 and when I perform the slope function within excel on the above numbers, I also return the same slope.

On a more varied set:

```
1             0.6 
2             0.9 
3             0.5 
4             1 
5             1 
6             0.84 
7             0.4 
8             1 
9             1 
10            1 
11            1 
12            1 
13            1 
14            0.8 
15            0.9 
16            1 
17            1 
18            1 
19            1 
20            1 
21            1
```

Access returns 0.02323, those same numbers in Excel and the slope shown on the graph return .0144

At this point I haven’t been able to find a solution as to why the slope is returning the way it is and I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note: the first index by default in a VBA array is 0, so this code is ignoring the data point in the first row.

Comment: Sure was simple. I set ctr = -1 before looping the recordset and that solved everything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've written this as an answer, so you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: @Tundrasama Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!  You selected a tag containing a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first index by default in a VBA array is 0, so this code is ignoring the data point in the first row.